# Issues with microhttpd when compiling ofxHttpServer

Tags: c++, static-libraries, openframeworks

I'm developing a program on openFrameworks that uses the [ofxHttpServer](https://github.com/arturoc/ofxHttpServer) addon.

My teammates can compile it on Windows on other computers. But I get errors related to microhttpd, which ofxHttpServer uses.

On line 965 of [microhttpd.h](https://github.com/arturoc/ofxHttpServer/blob/master/libs/microhttpd/include/microhttpd.h),

```
typedef ssize_t
  (*MHD_ContentReaderCallback) (void *cls,
                uint64_t pos,
                char *buf,
                size_t max);
```

I get several errors, including:

- C2065: 'MHD_ContentReaderCallback' : undeclared identifier
- IntelliSense: function returning function is not allowed

The openFrameworks project has "...\libmicrohttpd\include" in the additional include directories and "...\libmicrohttpd\lib" in the additional library directories.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Windows compiler does not know what ssize_t is.  That is defined by a GNU C include file (I googled it).  How are you compiling it?  Perhaps the project hasn't been setup to be compiled using Windows compilers?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. FOr some reason, when I got a copy of my teammate's project, the microhhtpd.h missed the following lines:

`#if defined( __WIN32__ ) || defined( _WIN32 )
typedef SSIZE_T ssize_t; //convey Windows type to unix type
typedef UINT64 uint64_t; //convey Windows type to unix type
typedef UINT16 uint16_t; //convey Windows type to unix type
#endif`

Comment: However, now I get linker errors related to MHD. I'll keep researching.

Comment: I'm just guessing, but one or more of those call backs may be required.  Meaning the user may be required to define them.